# How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in Oracle server?

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, string-aggregation

I have a table with data like this:

```
ID, END_DATE,   CLOSE_DATE

1,  2018-05-18, 2018-05-15 

2,  2018-05-18, 2018-05-14

3,  2018-05-18, 2018-05-11

4,  2018-05-18, 2018-05-10
```

I need the output when i query in Oracle server

```
 END_DATE    CLOSE_DATE                                    ID

 2018-05-18  [2018-05-15,2018-05-14,2018-05-11,2018-05-10] [1,2,3,4]
```

I have tried to use listagg, but its working either for Id or Close Date but not both.

```
select (listagg(CLOSE_DATE,',') within group (order by CLOSE_DATE DESC)) CLOSE_DATE
     , END_DATE
  from TBL_S_PLCLOSEDATE
 where D_END='18-MAY-2018'
```

Please let me know how to write the sql for the same in Oracle server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
select end_date,
       listagg(CLOSE_DATE, ',') within group (order by CLOSE_DATE DESC) as close_dates,
       listagg(id, ',') within group (order by id) as ids
from TBL_S_PLCLOSEDATE
where D_END = date '2018-05-18'
group by end_date;
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the date format from DD-MON-YYY (16-JUN-2018) to 16/06/2018 in Close_dates?

Comment: @Vasanth . . . You would use `to_char()`.